# How to prevent the data changes when clicking on navlinks separately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from `jsonplaceholder api` using `/posts` and `/click` links using the `<Link/>` router in react.

For now, it fetches its own data the problem is that when I click on `postlink`, the album data also changes that is not what I wanted, I want the album data not to change on clicking `postlink` similarly to `albumlink` too.

It should be like *when user clicks separately on the `postlink` it shouldn't change its data, while clicking on the `albumlink` at the same time.*

Here is some code snippets:

- App.js

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Album from './pages/Album';
import Posts from './pages/Posts';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { DataContext } from './context/DataContext.js';
import { useFetch } from './hook/useFetch';

export default function App() {
  const { posts, setPosts } = useFetch(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    []
  );

  const { albums, setAlbums } = useFetch(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
    []
  );

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{ posts, setPosts, albums, setAlbums }}>
      <div>
        <Navbar setPosts={setPosts} setAlbums={setAlbums} />
        <Posts posts={posts} />
        <Album albums={albums} />
      </div>
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

- Posts.js (fetch posts data)

```
import React, { useRef, useContext } from 'react';

export default function Posts({ posts }) {
  const shuffledPosts = posts.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, 3);

  return (
    <>
      <h4>below is posts data: </h4>
      {shuffledPosts.map((i) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div key={i.id}>
              {i.id}: <h3>{i.title}</h3>
              <p>{i.body}</p>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

- Album.js: (fetch albums data)

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export default function Album({ albums }) {
  const shuffledalbums = albums.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, 3);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h4>below is the album data</h4>
        {shuffledalbums.map((i, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <label key={i.id}>
                <i>
                  {`${i.id}: ${i.title}`}
                  <br />
                </i>
              </label>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

- navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Navbar({ setPosts, setAlbums }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Link
        to="#link1"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation(); //I used this but doesn't work for me
          setPosts((shuffledPosts) => [...shuffledPosts, shuffledPosts]);
        }}
      >
        postlink
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link
        to="#link2"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          setAlbums((shuffledAlbums) => [...shuffledAlbums, shuffledAlbums]);
        }}
      >
        albumlink
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link to="#link3">commentlink</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Demo link:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gwe7dt?file=src%2Fpages%2FPosts.js)

Please help me with this!

PS: for clarification, Whenever I click on the `postlink, I found that the album data also changes which is not what I want. I wanted it not to change until the user changes the link (post data shouldn't be changed).

Comment: Do you want to fetch only posts data on clicking `navLink1` and fetch only album data on clicking `navLink2`? Is this the requirement? could you also add the definition of the `useFetch` hook to the question?

Comment: I edited my question, I mean when I click on `navlink1` it shouldn't change its data while clicking on `navlink2` at the same time.

Comment: sorry, I earlier added the incorrect link now it is working mode. Please help me!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "when I click on navlink1 it shouldn't change its data while clicking on navlink2 at the same time."?

Comment: I think you check the demo link. I mean like whenever I am clicking on `navlink1`  it changes its data at the same time while clicking on another link. for ex: (when user click on `About` link only about data user gets and it stays until user doesn't click on other link)   Hope you understood!

Comment: can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my code? :(